# How to pass a filename from a second instance of a program to the main instance?

Tags: delphi, message-queue, message

Let say an instance of my program is running. It has 'File1.My' open (whatever that is).
Now the user double clicks in WinExplorer 'File2.My'. The 'My' extension is associated with my program so, a second instance will start. I use WMCOPYDATA to pass the filename ('File2') from the second instance to the first instance. The first instance will receive the filename load that file. The second instance will closed itself.

My problem is that the WMCOPYDATA message might appear while the first instance is showing a dialog box like "Are you sure you want to save File1 to disk?".
When the message arrives, first instance will load File2 **while** the dlg box is shown on screen asking about 'File1'.
So, how I handle this??

1. Maybe by putting the Load(File2) in a queue that I process after the dialog box closes?
2. Or maybe I should filter from the message queue the WMCopyData when a modal dialog box is open?
3. Use some kind of flag: if WMCopyDataReceived_Flag then Abort_current_code_after_the_dlgbox

All 3 seems more complicated than necesary.

Comment: The user opened the second file and is expecting something to happen. If nothing does they will likely open it a couple more times wondering what is going on. What to do depends on if your application can have multiple files open at once - opening file2 in another tab would be common in a lot of applications these days.

Comment: @Brian-Nope. It is critical that only one file is open at a time!

Comment: @Brian - If the file cannot be open, a message is sent back to the second instance, to let the user know that.

Comment: There are several disadvantages that come with the "only one instance" approach and the biggest is: when you think the instance has terminated but continues to run for hours (until you check the taskman) and you try to start one (i.e. thru double clicking a file) nothing seems to happen. Again and again.

Comment: Well then you should dismiss the WMCOPYDATA message while UI is doing something which does not allow the new file to be loaded... this will require you to set some flag to detect if that....

Comment: Solved with: "if Application.ModalLevel <> 0 then LoadFile"

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that the WMCOPYDATA message might appear while the first instance is showing a dialog box like "Are you sure you want to save File1 to disk?".
> When the message arrives, first instance will load File2 while the dlg box is shown on screen asking about 'File1'.

What is wrong with that?  The dialog's message loop will still dispatch the `WM_COPYDATA` message to the correct window message procedure.  You should be treating each file individually.  Does you app not allow multiple files to be loaded at the same time?

> So, how I handle this??
>
> 1. Maybe by putting the Load(File2) in a queue that I process after the dialog box closes?

If you don't want the new file loaded while the dialog is running, then yes, this is what you will have to do.  Especially since the user could try to load multiple files (or even the same file multiple times) while the dialog is running.

Otherwise, simply ignore the `WM_COPYDATA` message altogether while the dialog is running.  Perhaps send another message back to the 2nd instance telling it that the `WM_COPYDATA` message was ignored, so it can then notify the user to try again later.  After the 2nd instance sends `WM_COPYDATA`, make it wait a few seconds before exiting, in case such a reply comes in.  Perhaps always send a reply back, either ACK or NACK accordingly, and make the 2nd instance wait for either reply.

> 2. Or maybe I should filter from the message queue the WMCopyData when a modal dialog box is open?

No, especially since you don't have access to do that kind of filtering anyway.  `WM_COPYDATA` is a [*sent* message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#nonqueued-messages), not a [*posted* message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages), so the message queue won't ever see it, but performing message retrieval on the message queue will automatically dispatch it.

> 3. Use some kind of flag: if WMCopyDataReceived_Flag then Abort_current_code_after_the_dlgbox

I don't even understand what you are trying to do with that.